# Should the compiler warn on pointer arithmetic with a void pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

I was compiling C program using gcc 4.7.2. I have sum a address which is void * type with some offset.  (void* + size) should give warning. If it is not then how many bytes it will be added to if size is 1  & if size is 50.
my only concern at should give warning that we are adding something to void pointer ?

```
 12         int size = 50;
 /*Allocate a block of memory*/
 14         void *BlockAddress   = malloc(200);
 15         if(!BlockAddress)
 16                  return -1;
 17         address1             = (int *)BlockAddress;
 18         address2             = BlockAddress + 1*size;
 19         address3             = BlockAddress + 2*size;
```

Thanks

Comment: You can check, but I think it will add 4 bytes (size of pointer) if it works. Unless you specify the type, there is no way for the compiler to know how many bytes to add. E.g. for char 1 byte is added, for int pointer 4 bytes are added, and so on. So, i think the default value will be the pointer size which is 4 bytes.

Comment: yes I have already checked it. And i was thinking the same as you are thinking unless i have compiled it and ran it, this program compiled  without error or warning. And it is adding 1 not 4, thats why asked the question why it is like that.?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are not supposed to do pointer arithmetic on void pointers.

From the C Standard

> 6.5.6-2: For addition, either both operands shall have arithmetic type, or one operand shall be a pointer to an object type and the other shall have integer type.
>
> 6.2.5-19: The void type comprises an empty set of values; it is an incomplete type that cannot be completed.

GNU C allows the above by considering the size of `void` is `1`.

From *[6.23 Arithmetic on void- and Function-Pointers](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html)*:

> In GNU C, addition and subtraction operations are supported on pointers to void and on pointers to functions. This is done by treating the size of a void or of a function as 1.

So going by the above lines we get:

```
 address2             = BlockAddress + 1*size; //increase by 50 Bytes
 address3             = BlockAddress + 2*size; //increase by 100 Bytes
```

Comment: `gcc` says `warning: pointer of type 'void *' used in arithmetic` on this.

Comment: Thanks Acme, at least this make some sense as you said "GNU C allows the above by considering the size of void is 1" now the size of void is one sound horrible ? does not it ?

Comment: @Javed - yes that is what my answer states i believe.

Comment: @Javed - They must have had a reason for doing so - since they also give lots of other features as extension. C is one heck of a language you never stop learning C.

Comment: Acme you are absolutely right. your answer is really helpful. thanks

Answer (score 10):

Pointer arithmetic with `void *` is a [GCC extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html) and not standard C.

Better don't do things like these. Either use a `char * BlockAddress = malloc(200);` or cast it for `address2` and `address3` as well.

Comment: Why would they come up with such a mindless extension? That is mad.

Comment: Thanks I know that i have type cast for proper operation, lets say by chance i have forget to typecast so it should give me at warning or more proper it should give me a error ?

Comment: That depends on the warning level and options you gave.

Comment: @Rob I'd find it useful, but as it is a GCC extension, it is better not to use it.

Comment: @Javed Then it should warn you.

Comment: okey i found -Wpointer-arith,  it will tell us like   warning: pointer of type ‘void *’ used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly valid.  The void* contains an address and adding one is just pointing to the next byte in memory.  Nothing to worry about here...

Comment: Thanks It'sPate,  but dont you think that if take int ptr then it will increment with 4 bytes and double with 8 bytes while char pointer with 1 byte only, so what is defind for void ? that is 1. thats why not because it goes to next position ..