# C (void**)a+1 , why the interval（step） is 8？

Tags: c, pointers

like this:

```c
void** a = calloc(4,4);
printf("%x,%x",a,a+1));
```

the result is
`1516c0,1516c8`

why the step is 8?
I don't want use (char*) to convert the type,what should I do?

Comment: Pointer arithmetic. `sizeof (void *)` is 8 on your system, so `a + 1` goes 8 bytes forward to go to the next `void *`. Also the correct format specifier for pointers is `%p`.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You forgot important details. What step did you expect? 4? 1? Why? "what should I do?" What do you want to achieve?

Comment: As mediocrevegetable1 mentioned, pointers need format specifier `%p`. And to be precise you must provide `void*` which means you need to cast your `void**` to `void*` for printing it.

Comment: As with array indexing, adding 1 moves to the next *element* not the next *byte*. `a + 1` is the same as `&a[1]`.

Comment: I want to make the step become 1

Comment: Step by 1 *what*? For what purpose? Adding `1` does make it step by 1. Why do you `calloc(4,4)` when the pointer size on your system is clearly `8`?

Comment: Use `%p` to print pointer values, not `%x`.  On a typical 64-bit system, pointers are 8 bytes and integers are 4 bytes, so at best you'd only be printing half of the pointers, and you may not be printing any of the second pointer at all.

Comment: "I want to make the step become 1" The less horrible solutions for that involve "use (char*) to convert the type", which you do NOT want. Please decide what is the more important of those two requirements. You might also want to take one logical step back and describe what you really want to achieve, i.e. please consider whether we are looking at a https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: `a+1` depends on the type of `a`, not on the address of `a` (nor the number of bytes reserved at that address).

Comment: pointer arithmetic on `void*` is illegal. Duplicate: [Pointer arithmetic for void pointer in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3523145/995714), [Should the compiler warn on pointer arithmetic with a void pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20967868/995714), [Why does incrementing a void pointer by 1 moves one byte ahead but it's 4 bytes for an integer pointer,8 for double?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16336757/995714)

Comment: @phuclv Pointer arithmetic on `void**` isn't, however.

Answer (score 2):

Printing pointers with `%x` isn't well-defined, you should use `%p` instead.

`a+1` performs pointer arithmetic on type `void**`, meaning you get the byte size of the pointed-at item, a `void*`. So depending on how large such a pointer is on your system, you'll get an address change accordingly. Apparently your system has 64 bit pointers (likely 64 bit address bus) hence 8 bytes.

Using absolute values to `calloc` is fishy code overall. Not sure what you are trying to achieve with that.

If you want a type-generic pointer that can iterate through generic chunks of data byte by byte, the correct type to use is `unsigned char*`. If you don't want to use that for some artificial reason, then tough luck - no can do.

Comment: since when is arithmetic on void* defined?

Comment: @Raildex Since the first C standard? It's arithmetic leading to pointed-at `void` which isn't defined. So if it had been `void* a`, the code wouldn't compile. `void**` is however just an ordinary pointer type without special rules.

Comment: yes, I would like use "generic-type" in c, because some type size is less than 8B eg: int is 4B, I want to move the pointer byte by byte. I use the (char*) , it work pretty.Is  necessary change it?

Comment: @GuoHaodong That's what I wrote in the answer, yes? Except it should be `unsigned char*` if you mean to access the data through that pointer. `char*` has implementation-defined signedness and therefore shouldn't be used when dealing with raw binary data.

Answer (score 0):

As mentiond the size of `void *` is 8 on your system so it goes 8 bytes forward. Any way, you just need to change some thing and you don't need to use `char *` for this case. In addition, using `%p` to print pointers is a better choice:

```
void** a = calloc(4, sizeof(void *));
printf("%p,%p",a,a+1));
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you have a problem with understanding the difference between the physical addresses and the references. Pointer arithmetic in C is done using the objects referenced by the pointers. When you print the pointer using "%p" or "%x" (not good as it is wrong format) you get the physical (byte) address.

1. You probably use `void **` because pointer arithmetics on `void *` does not work on most compilers that do not have special extensions as `gcc`.
2. If you want the `address` to be increased by one simply use `char *` pointer instead of `void *`
3. If you want to print the difference in pointer arithmetics (not physical bytes):

```
int main(void)
{
    void **a;
    printf("%" PRIiPTR "\n", a - (a+1));
}
```